# Outlook: How to safely loop through all stores and and set ItemAdd event to all default folders for sent mail?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

For the case you have more accounts/stores in your Outlook and want that ItemAdd event fires e.g. for all sent items folder.

This is what I have so far but the event is not firing for all sent items folder:

```
foreach (Outlook.Store store in _outlookNameSpace.Stores)
{
    // _SentItems = null;
    // _items = null;

    try
    {
        _SentItems = store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

        _items = _SentItems.Items;
        _items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd); // BUGBUG: The problem is probably here, as the object needs to be alive which is firing the event?
    }
    catch
    {
        AppUtils.DoLog("Skipping this store.");
    }

}
```

These guys are defined as global class variables:

```
Outlook.NameSpace _outlookNameSpace;
Outlook.MAPIFolder _SentItems;
Outlook.Items _items;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper class that takes `Items` object as a parameter in its constructor, saves it in a field, and sets up an `ItemAdd` event handler. You can then initialize a wrapper for each store and store then in a list to ensure the wrappers (and their Items objects) stay alive and can raise events.

Comment: As always thank you very much Dmitry. Any code sample which could help me?

Comment: I don't have a ready to use sample, but it is trivial to implement.