# Add Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler to all Stores

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm in the process of creating an Outlook addon that triggers an event when a new email arrives in an Inbox. But my profile has multiple Stores of multiple types so in my loop through all stores I filter only the mailbox types (to exclude the shared folders or other items). Then I want to add an event to the inbox of that store.

All works well except... it only works on one store, not on all. It's always the last in the sequence but the sequence is random hence the fact that the trigger is always on a different inbox. I'm pretty sure I need to add an identifier somewhere to distinguish the store in the event. But what am I overlooking?

My code so far (which works but only on one Inbox):

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
    Outlook.Items items;
    Outlook.NameSpace ns;
    Outlook.Stores stores;
    Outlook.Store store;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        stores = ns.Stores;

        for (int i = 1; i <= stores.Count; i++)
        {
            store = stores[i];

            if (store.ExchangeStoreType == OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox || store.ExchangeStoreType == OlExchangeStoreType.olPrimaryExchangeMailbox || store.ExchangeStoreType == OlExchangeStoreType.olAdditionalExchangeMailbox) 
            {
                inbox = store.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                items = inbox.Items;
                items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
            }

            if (store != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
        }
    }
    
    void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        if (Item != null)
        {
            if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note")
            {
                Debug.Print("A new email has arrived.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056516/outlook-how-to-safely-loop-through-all-stores-and-and-set-itemadd-event-to-all) was asked in the past but I don't understand where the Items object should go. I understand what the issue is but not the right idea to solve it.
Anyone who can give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper class for each `Store` object - make it take an instance of the `Store` object in the constructor, retrieve the Inbox folder using `Store.GetDefaultFolder`, store `Items` object in that wrapper class, and set up the `ItemAdd` event handler. Your addin call store all the wrappers in a list (`List<MyStoreWrapper>`) - you can add new wrappers to that list in your loop over `Namespace.Stores`.

Comment: You're right (again) ;-) Your answer in the other question was a bit too cryptic for me, this one made the learning curve slightly less steep. Got it working now.  Thanks.